# semi-order and the existence of n for $10^n+1$ divisible by 49

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to show that there are infinite many $n$ such that $10^n+1$ is divisible by 49.

I am aware of the answer

[Find all numbers of form $10^k+1$ divisible by $49$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149835/find-all-numbers-of-form-10k1-divisible-by-49)

But would ask for a more general method.

For this, it seems that this is related to the order of 10. We know that $10^{\phi(49)}-1$ is divisible by 49, but we need a sort of “semi-version” of Euler’s theory, namely $a^{f(n)}\equiv -1 \bmod n$ for some $f(n)$.

I am not sure whether there is a theory on the “semi-order”. Moreover, while this is imaginable for prime $p$, I need a similar thing for $p^2$.